# Photonview.owner.nickname not working properly for Clients

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm working on photon game where I have to show the player name over their everything is working fine but there's an issue , when you create a room and join it , the host name is properly visible to everyone but when it comes to the client Client name is some random numbers even though client is also setting their user name before joining the room , here's my code which is handling the naming system

```
public void JoinRoom()
{
    connectButton.interactable = false;
    PhotonNetwork.NickName = userId.text;
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom("Basic");
}
```

Comment: Please include the portion where you display the client name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    PhotonView view;
    
void Start()
    {

        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }
void JoinRoom()
    {
        if(view.IsMine)
        {
            userId.text = PhotonNetwork.NickName;
        }else

        {
            userId..text = view.Owner.NickName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).